# Passing variables to next page

Tags: php, sql, variables

I have passed 2 variables from one page to the next, but am having trouble with the _GET and WHERE clause in my receiving page.

I suspect the issue lies with the WHERE clause:

WHERE vertrek = '$vertrek' AND aankomst = '$aankomst'

The pertinent code is:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");//GET and POST
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");//POST

if (!isset($_GET['vid']) || !is_numeric($_GET['vid'])) {
die("Invalid ID specified.");
}
$vertrek = (int)$_GET['vid'];

if (!isset($_GET['aid']) || !is_numeric($_GET['aid'])) {
die("Invalid ID specified.");
}
$aankomst = (int)$_GET['aid'];


$result = mysql_query("select vg.gegevenID, vg.vertrektijd, vg.vertrekluchthaven AS     
vertrek, lh.luchthavencode, vg.aankomstluchthaven AS aankomst, lh2.luchthavencode,  
vg.vertrekdatum, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, t.toestel, vg.inschrijvingnmr

from tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

left join tbl_luchthaven lh
on vg.vertrekluchthaven = lh.luchthavenID

left join tbl_luchthaven lh2
on vg.aankomstluchthaven = lh2.luchthavenID

left join tbl_toestel t
on vg.toestel = t.toestelID

left join tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
on vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID

WHERE vertrek = '$vertrek' AND aankomst = '$aankomst'
ORDER BY vg.vertrekdatum2 DESC");
```

Comment: what is the error message shown

Comment: `WHERE vertrek = '" . $vertrek . "' AND aankomst = '" . $aankomst . "'`

Comment: Try echo both the values `$vertrek` and `$aankomst`

Comment: Also, have you validated your query by running it directly in MySQL with valid values substituted for the variables?

Comment: mhasan, the error message is:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .... on line 58  

DevlshOne: i think we're on the right track here..

Mohit Bhansali, yes, I can echo the $vertrek & $aankomst and it gives me the correct parameters.

Comment: Revent. I ran the code in Toad and figured it out... (I'm very new to this)...

Comment: It should be 
WHERE vertrekluchthaven = '" . $vertrek . "' AND aankomstluchthaven = '" . $aankomst . "'

it did not like my "alisas'"